# Insert from one table to another with unique vales

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, unique

I have a query to update Table 1 from table 2

```
Insert into Table1 (Column A, Column B, Column C,Column D)
Select Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D from Table 2
```

I want to run this is a cron to keep Table 2 updated as new records are added to Table 1. However I do NOT want duplicates as defined by Columns A-C.

I thought if I made a Unique Index in Table 2 using Column A, Column B, Column C it would simply not add new records unless they did not exist with those three columns but all I get is an error

> Duplicate entry exists 'Column A-Column B-Column C' for key 'Unique'

Is there anyway to set this up so that only new records are updated from the cron?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and insert only records that do not exists in table 1 based on your 3 columns:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,ColumnD)  
SELECT t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB, t2.ColumnC, t2.ColumnD 
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
  ON t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA
 AND t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB
 AND t1.ColumnC = t2.ColumnC
WHERE t1.ColumnA IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab3c9/1/0)**</kbd>

I've assumed that `ColumnA-C` are compound `PRIMARY KEY`.

**EDIT:**

You can use `MySQL` [`INSERT IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1 (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,ColumnD)  
SELECT t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB, t2.ColumnC, t2.ColumnD 
FROM Table2 t2;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2da15/1/0)**</kbd>

If you need to update rest of columns with newer values you can use:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,ColumnD)  
SELECT t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB, t2.ColumnC, t2.ColumnD 
FROM Table2 t2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ColumnD = VALUES(ColumnD);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo3`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c147d/1/0)**</kbd>

There is also [`REPLACE INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) (slower and will remove old record + insert new one):

```
REPLACE INTO Table1 (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,ColumnD)  
SELECT t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB, t2.ColumnC, t2.ColumnD 
FROM Table2 t2
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo4`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df791/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Over thinking this one again?

Comment: @Strawberry `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`? IGNORE I see

Comment: @Strawberry But there is good site of it.  Learning something new :)

Answer (score 0):

If any of your column has unique value (e.g. column A is your PRIMARY KEY) you can use:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D)
SELECT Column_A, Column_B, Column_C, Column_D 
FROM table2 
WHERE column_A NOT IN (
  SELECT column_A FROM table1
);
```

This statement will insert into table1 entries with values of Column_A of table2 that are not exists in Column_A of table1.